# ParerError Need help figuring it out

Tags: parser

[image: parserError]

I'm following along a tutorial on this, but the other person is using an older version of solidity and I am super new to the field. I'm not sure where it went wrong but even though our screen matches up, i get an error.

Comment: you don't need payable inside transfer(....)! and you show use more of the contract? what is "wallet" ? is it address or payable address?

Comment: I believe @Majd TL comment above is correct. You should not have the payable keyword inside the transfer(msg.value) param.

I would make it easier for people to help you further if you share the link to the tutorial you are using as reference, even if outdated.